# How to provide computed number of workgroups to glDispatchComputeIndirect?

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

How is glDispatchComputeIndirect supposed to work if you want to calculate the number of threads of the second dispatch in the first one?

I have a compute shader that runs over a buffer, checks if the value of the element is valid, and then conditionally writes the index of the element into another buffer with the help of an atomic counter. How can I now dispatch a second compute shader with one thread for each written index most efficiently?

The probably slowest solution is to read back the value *n* of the atomic counter and glDispatchCompute(*n* / workgroupSize, 1, 1).

I thought about using glDispatchComputeIndirect and preparing the dispatch indirect buffer in the first compute shader. But the values in the dispatch indirect buffer are expected to be integer numbers of workgroups, not numbers of threads, so I cannot simply increment an atomic counter per written element. I could dispatch another compute shader with one thread that only divides the number of written elements by the workgroup size, but that's not a proper solution.

I could also still use the atomic "element counter" for counting of written elements, check the return value in each thread and increment another atomic "workgroup counter" whenever the return value of atomicAdd is divisible by the workgroup size. This saves me a return trip to the CPU and a third dispatch, but at the cost of another atomic counter. But I cannot think of any better solution right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the number of "threads". You need the number of workgroups. So calculate the thing you need to calculate.

The relationship between number of workgroups in the second dispatch call and the number of "threads" you compute is simple: `(threadCount / threadPerGroup)`, where `threadPerGroup` is the number of invocations in the workgroup of the second compute shader.

Now you don't need to compute all of `threadCount` to compute this. All you really have to do is bump an atomic counter every time you increment `threadCount` past a multiple of `threadPerGroup` times. Which is easy enough, since `atomicCounterIncrement` returns the previous value of the atomic counter.

So your code would look like this:

```
if(<I should add a thread>)
{
  uint oldThreadCount = atomicCounterIncrement(threadCount); //Returns old value
  if(oldThreadCount % threadPerGroup == 0) //That means `threadCount` is now in the next group.
    atomicCounterIncrement(groupCount);
}
```